# Extracting Propreties to Styles (Xaml processing tool)

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I need to extract the props (Height, Width, HorizontalAligment .. etc) of a control to a style.

**Do you guys know any tool to do that?**

I have tried Xaml Power tools (nice, but only handles xml like attribute properties for ex:  is not recognized)
Also looked over expression blend.. didn't find anything there either.

At least some framework/api for easy parsing of xaml (found Xaml Toolkit, but it remained in CTP version in 2010..)

Thanks!

Comment: Question.  Parsing the Xaml would give you only the style properties that had been set locally.  Properties that had been set by other methods, such as WPF coercion, or from binding, or from a resource dictionary already existing in the object graph, or even  derived from a templated parent would be missing.  So are you wishing to capture only those properties which have been set locally and declaratively?  Or are you seeking to capture the visual appearance of an element after it has been constructed?

Comment: Did you find the answer posted below to be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an element and specified properties such as the Slider control below.

```
<Window x:Class="Styling.ExtractStyle"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ViewTemplateSource" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="g1">
        <Slider Name="mySlider" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Slider.Width>200</Slider.Width>
        </Slider>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can implement an extension to the FrameworkElement class...

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
{
    public static void SaveElementStyleToFile(this FrameworkElement element, string fileName)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                IndentChars = new string(' ', 4),
                NewLineOnAttributes = true
            };
            StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
            XmlWriter xmlwrite = XmlWriter.Create(strbuild, settings);
            if (xmlwrite != null)
            {
                XamlWriter.Save(element, xmlwrite);
            }
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, strbuild.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot serialize a null object");
        }
    }
}
```

And call the extension method...

```
mySlider.SaveElementStyleToFile("mySliderStyle.xaml");
```

This will give you an XML file in the root directory of your application which captures the 'hard-coded' properties.  Here's what it outputs...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Slider
    Name="mySlider"
    Width="200"
    Height="100"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
```

You can then morph this file into a persistent style with an editor.  Note that the target Framework element must be first run through WPF's two pass layout system for this technique to work.

For example

TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Height = 20;
t.SaveElementStyleToFile("myfile.xml");

will *NOT* work for that reason.  Short of the conveniences offered by Xaml Power Toys and/or a full Xaml parser, this is likely to be as close as you will get to meeting your requirements...